# Grade sync fails after cordova prepare android

Tags: android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

After adding android to my Ionic project, and following the documentation, I can only get the following error in Android Studio:

```
ERROR: startup failed:
build file '/Users/dev/Developer/diningcity-assistant/platforms/android/app/build.gradle': 297: expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway @ line 297, column 24.
       implementation27.+"
                          ^

1 error

Open File
```

I cannot figure out what this "implementation" line is for:

```
    implementation27.+"
    implementation27.+"
```

They show two times in my dependencies {} section, and I don't know what they are supposed to do or why they are here.

Removing them did allow Gradle to sync again, but I have no idea if I may have actually removed a component that is actually critical to the app functioning properly.

I've searched everywhere for an answer on this but nobody seems to have experienced this so far.

Here is the info of what I'm building with:

```
ionic info

Ionic:

   Ionic CLI                     : 5.4.12 (/Users/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.4.0-dev.201904251558.2457a23
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.8
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.2.3
   @angular/cli                  : 7.2.3
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.2.3

Capacitor:

   Capacitor CLI   : 1.0.0-beta.22
   @capacitor/core : 1.0.0-beta.19

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.1.0, ios 5.1.1
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.4.1, (and 16 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed

System:

   ios-deploy : 1.9.4
   ios-sim    : 8.0.1
   NodeJS     : v12.1.0 (/Users/dev/.nvm/versions/node/v12.1.0/bin/node)
   npm        : 6.9.0
   OS         : macOS Catalina
   Xcode      : Xcode 11.2.1 Build version 11B500

`gradle -v

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 5.4.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2019-04-26 08:14:42 UTC
Revision:     261d171646b36a6a28d5a19a69676cd098a4c19d

Kotlin:       1.3.21
Groovy:       2.5.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.13 compiled on July 10 2018
JVM:          1.8.0_211 (Oracle Corporation 25.211-b12)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.15.1 x86_64`
```